# Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. ASP.NET SQL DataSource

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Although, there are a lot of questions with this title, but mine is different.

I am using a ASP.NET ListView bound to a sql datasource control & as such have not added any conversions. Also I am sending `DBNull` value in ListView's Inserting Event.

**The DataSource Code:**

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Main %>"  InsertCommand="pInsert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    SelectCommand="pGet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"   >
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Code" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="SubscriptionCode" SessionField="EntryCode" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Attachment" Type="Object" />

            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>                
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="SubscriptionCode" SessionField="EntryCode" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="ForEdit" Type="Boolean" />
            </SelectParameters>           
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**The Code Behind :**

```
protected void lv_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {           
            e.Values["Attachment"] = DBNull.Value;
        }
```

I have also tried removing the `Type="Object"` property as specified [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304133428/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120606-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Type="Object"` property from this line `<asp:Parameter Name="Attachment" Type="Object" />` and try this in code behind :

```
protected void lv_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
   e.Values["Attachment"] = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null;
}
```

Comment: Both solutions work but i would mark this as answer because -1 consumes space & is not null in the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Just try the code below.

**The DataSource Code :**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Main %>"  InsertCommand="pInsert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
SelectCommand="pGet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"   >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Code" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="SubscriptionCode" SessionField="EntryCode" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Attachment" />

    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>                
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="SubscriptionCode" SessionField="EntryCode" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="ForEdit" Type="Boolean" />
    </SelectParameters>           
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**The Code Behind :**

```
protected void lv_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
   e.Values["Attachment"] = -1;
}
```